# TYPO3 felogin localization

Tags: localization, typo3, felogin

In TYPO3 v11.5.31 I want to change the default translation of the felogin plugin. I know it is supposed to be working like this in the TS Setup:

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1._LOCAL_LANG.de {
  welcome_message = New Text
}
```

But it does not. It works for other plugins that way (for instance tx_srfeuserregister), but felogin does not change the displayed text. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plugin.tx_felogin_pi1` is the plugin name for the piBase-based version of this plugin. The Extbase-based plugin has its configuration below `plugin.tx_felogin_login`.

So this should work:

```
plugin.tx_felogin_login._LOCAL_LANG.de {
  welcome_message = New Text
}
```

Comment: What an oversight on my part. That is correct!